# Передать параметр в функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот так при помощи juqery работаю с блоком:

```js
$(function() {
$('#div1').hover(function() { 
    $('#div2').fadeIn(); 
}, function() { 
    $('#div2').fadeOut(); 
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="div1">

<div id="div2">
</div>

</div>
```

Но блоков много, помогите передать по событию из блока в функцию juqery параметр, чтобы мне функцию для каждого блока не прописывать.
Напоминаю, я слабоват, буду очень рад подробностям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.inner').hide();

  $('.outer').hover(function() { 
      $(this).find('.inner').stop().fadeIn(); 
    }, function() { 
      $(this).find('.inner').stop().fadeOut(); 
  });
});
```

```css
div.outer {width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: lightblue;}
div.inner {width: 150px; height:  60px; background-color: darkviolet;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
    
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
   
</div>

<div class="outer" style="background-color: green;">
    
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: red;">
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Но фактически получается так ничего и не изменится, для каждого блока мне придется дублировать функцию? Или это нормально? Хотелось бы присвоить блокам идентификаторы и передавать их в одну функцию

Comment: @EugenEray - спасибо, стало гораздо нагляднее

Comment: @Vadim - а теперь?

Comment: По большому счету работает правильно, как я хотел. Но случилась неприятность, я заметил инерцию, если курсором поводить туда-сюда потом еще долго моргает(в моем варианте тоже самое). Может знаете как малой кровью это исправить или плагин какой?

Comment: @Vadim Это уже другой вопрос :). Смотрите изменения в ответе.

Comment: Работает идеально, от меня и от всех кому пригодится огромное спасибо. Если бы еще кто-нибудь ссылку на плагин кинул для сглаживания... Что-то типа как для animate http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ Впрочем, это уже другая история, как сказал бы Леонид Каневский

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать и без `JavaScript` например:

```css
.outer {background-color: violet; width: 260px; height: 220px;}
.inner {opacity: 0; background-color: blue; width: 130px; height: 130px; margin: 20px auto; position: relative;}

.inner:hover {animation: fade 2s linear; animation-fill-mode: forwards; animation-iteration-count: 1;}


@keyframes fade {
0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"></div>
<div>
```

Но получается очень дерганая анимация. Хотя если подшаманить, то можно и поправить, но вот вариант с jQuery

```js
$(".inner").mouseover(function(){
 $(".inner").animate({opacity: 1}, 900);
});

$(".inner").mouseout(function(){
 $(".inner").animate({opacity: 0}, 900);
});
```

```css
.outer {background-color: violet; width: 260px; height: 220px;}
.inner {background-color: blue; width: 130px; height: 130px; margin: 20px auto; position: relative; opacity: 0; z-index: 3;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

А если вы говорите, что блоков много, то добавьте им класс: `outer` для внешнего, а `inner` для внутреннего, ведь этот класс он просто служебный и в данном случае используется параметр `opacity`, только для того, чтобы элемент не убирался с экрана, а просто пропадал из виду.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, на стилях было бы элегантно, но немного не так как надо. Надо чтобы и большой и малый блоки оставались активными. При наведении курсора на большой, малый и большой становились активным. Моя дилетантская интуиция подсказывает что так невозможно, hover ложные срабатывания дает. Если у кого-нибудь есть готовое что-нибудь на css, скинте.